# How can I interpret "soundtrack" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, figurative-language

> Architecture and design guru William T. Georgis designed his dramatic
>   pool for his private West Coast getaway. A raised planter ingeniously
>   created planting space at the foot of a large retaining wall, which we
>   filled with statuesque junipers and striped flax. Water spilling from
>   pin jets into the pool is a lovely **soundtrack** in the already tranquil
>   spot.
>
> From Gardens are for Living: Design Inspiration for Outdoor Spaces by
>   Judy Kameon

How can I interpret “soundtrack” here? Does it mean background sound? Does it imply the sound makes the spot even more tranquil?

> Soundtrack:
>
> the sounds, especially the music, of a film, or a separate recording
>   of this:
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/soundtrack

Comment: The word ***already*** strongly implies that the "audio background" from the fountain jets ***augments the existing tranquility*** of the place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a metaphor.

A film has a soundtrack that provides background music and sounds.  The garden has background sound provided by a water fountain.  The sound of the water is metaphorically a soundtrack.

Since we are told that the spot is "already tranquil" and the sound of the water is "lovely" we can infer that the sound makes the space even more tranquil (and this is supported by our common knowledge of what water sounds like.)